# JQuery Карусель с различными эффектами смены картинки

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин jQuery карусели, чтобы выводилась одна картинка, с различными эффектами смены картинки, наподобие http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/demo-2/

Answer (score 1):

Возьми с этого сайта скрипты и все.
И проблем не будет.

Comment: чувак. ты гений )) но вообще интересует может что-то подобное и есть бесплатно )

Comment: @Heidel, а разве js-скрипты бывают платные? Ни разу не сталкивался, [вот вроде такой слайдер][1] 

[1]: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1094

Comment: Конечно, бывают, и их довольно много. Вот этот Nivo Slider, приведенный как пример, раньше был бесплатный, а потом бесплатную версию убрали, и он стал платный и только как плагин для вордпресс.

Comment: @Heidel, в данном случае это плагин, который даёт возможность установки слайдера в бесплатный движок, но можно прикрутить этот же скрипт бесплатно к вордпрессу, с этого же сайта из кода можно взять и JS и CSS